# How to turn off a bell in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: intellij-idea, vim, ideavim

Is there any way to turn off the sound which rings when a line is uncommented?

I find many ways to turn off sounds in IDEAvim, but I am asking about the sound above, not about a plugin. Default editor in Idea.

Answer (score 10):

Put this line into your `~/.ideavimrc` file:

`set visualbell`

See also `:help 'visualbell'` and the [list of `:set` commands](https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim/blob/master/doc/set-commands.md) supported by IdeaVim.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows, the bells can be easily modified or muted by changing the setting in the sound pannel.
You can click
`setting`->`system`->`more sound settings` to customize the windows sound solution, and by default, the error bell when typing in ideavim is called the default sound option in the sound solution, maybe changing to a more soft alert is a better option than muting it.